# Cannot get location services working with Swift and iOS8 with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, core-location

I did a lot of research about how to get location services working properly with Swift and `iOS8`. I know there are a lot of threads describing the common pitfalls but nothing did work for me.

This is the code of my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//#2
var gmaps: GMSMapView?

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var target: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.6, longitude: 17.2)
    var camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition(target: target, zoom: 6, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

    gmaps = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    if let map = gmaps? {
        map.camera = camera
        map.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(gmaps!)

        map.animateToZoom(10)
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if let map = gmaps? {
            map.myLocationEnabled = true
            map.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
        if let map = gmaps? {
            map.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my info plist I have set the keys `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and Privacy - Location Usage Description. I also added the `CoreLocation`.framework to my linked frameworks and libraries.

BUT I still do not get a popup asking the user for the location permissions. There is no error but also nothing else happening :-(

Comment: Have you tried on real device?

Comment: Yes, both on an simulator and on a real device (iPhone 6)

Comment: Hi did you enable Google Places API Web Service in Google Developers Console?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the permission is already granted for your app and if so, remove that permission (iOS settings app, privacy).

Another recommendation is to completely deinstall the app from simulator/device.

Here is a code snippet from my appDelegate, it uses `requestAlwaysAuthorization` but that shouldn't make a difference here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // intialize locationManager
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.Fitness
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10   // 10m
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // get current location
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Authorized {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    ...
}
```

And this is in my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>No tracking without your permission</string>
```

Comment: Checked the permissions - no permissions set for my app. Also reinstalling the app didn't help. This is so frustrating -.-

Comment: Notice that the simulator doesn't have GPS capabilities, you have to simulate a location.

Comment: Well anyway... I am testing on my device most of the time

Comment: What is the result of `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` at runtiime?

Comment: It returns `NotDetermined`

Comment: Remove the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key/value from `Info.plist` so you only have one.

Comment: Last idea from my side: The `value` of the `Info.plist` is really a `string`? And your deployment target is iOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems with CLLocationManager. You need request access if state is changed to `NotDetermined`. Example:

```
private var isInitalized = false
private func initLocationManagerIfNescessary() {
    if isInitalized { return }
    isInitalized = true

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    // locationManager.locationServicesEnabled
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    let iosVersion = NSString(string: Device.systemVersion).doubleValue
    let iOS8 = iosVersion >= 8
    if iOS8 {
        //locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() // add in plist NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // add in plist NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
    } else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

internal func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        // After first request status may be not autorized, do request access again
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, the code jumps into the right block of the switch statement and requests the authorization again but still no popup :-(

Comment: Try write simple new application with location manager. I'm sure that you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I put the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the Test .plist file.